# WebElement Object.text returns a specific string that can't be stripped

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver with Python3.
I've extracted a webelement with the following command:

```
ul = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.select2-selection__rendered')
```

this the HTML snipped I'm dealing with:

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="XX" data-select2-id="10"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>XX</li><li class="select2-selection__choice" title="admin" data-select2-id="11"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>admin</li><li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Test" data-select2-id="12"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Test</li><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
```

now if I do `ul.text` I get `×XX\n×admin\n×Test` and `type(ul.text)` returns `class str`
Now, wish to get rid of the small "x" in the beginning, so I split and take the first substring which is `xXX` and save it to variable `first`. 
I tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
first.strip('x')
first.replace('x', ' ') or first.replace('x', '')
first.split('x')
temp = copy.copy(first)
temp.split('x')
temp.replace('x', ' ') or temp.replace('x', '')
temp.strip('x')
```

However, if I manually write 'xXX' and do any of the above it works. Does anyone have an explanation and a solution for that?

used strip, replace, split and copy.copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "small x" in the beginning of "×XX\n×admin\n×Test" isn't an "x" it is a multiplication sign. (Alt + 0215 = ×). You can copy and paste the multiplication sign from your string or use my code below.

first.split('×')

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy from this :D, It looks like an x in my screen, only when I zoomed in and checked what I wrote here, did it look like a multiplication sign.